# Consideration to create a UI for CrouseControl.net

Tags: .net, open-source, user-interface, cruisecontrol.net, continuous-integration

As CrouseControl.net is an open source software and it is a good CI tool, I'm going to create a UI which make configuration easier than tricking XML.

So What are the considerations and necessities. I also need to know about any documentation which may help me to implement UI.

like a XML tag refrences or something else.

any help will appriciated.

Comment: Do you still want to create a new software ?

Comment: @TridenT, Yes I'm still want to create a UI for CC.NET, The one you introduced was to simple, I want to create something like TeamCity UI.

Answer (score 3):

**CCNetConfig** do exactly the same thing : create configuration file. You will find many resources in the website.

http://ccnetconfig.codeplex.com/

Even if I think xml config file are really-really simple and readable.

Comment: @naxa Latest version is v0.6.46726.1 Beta - Feb 12, 2009.
So it should work, but not for new feature of 1.4+